# jQuery slideDown/Up and responsive designs

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design

I have a menu that resizes responsively, so the contents of a div (`#menuWFhover`) are re-arranged with each resize, and as a consequence the div has different heights depending on the window size.

When I use jQuery `slideDown/Up`, it works fine the first time but after a resize the div maintains the height of the previous animation. Is this because slideDown plays with the height to animate? This is a simplified version of what I'm using. If I replace/add a `(windows)resize` (which is my guess, that it has something to do with it) the animation doesn't happen, but I might be doing it wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var WFover = function () {
            $('#menuWFhover').stop().slideDown(300);
        };
        var WFout = function () {
            $('#menuWFhover').stop().slideUp(300);
        };

        $('#menuNewBox').mouseover(WFover);
        $('#menuWFhover').mouseover(WFover);
        $('#menuNewBox').mouseout(WFout);
        $('#menuWFhover').mouseout(WFout);
});
```

Comment: hey can we see the css of #menuWFhover #menuNewBox

Comment: I've encountered this problem many times. It's because of the stop(). If you stop while it's animation, it sets the new height of the element to the height where it stopped. You could use stop(true, true), which forces the animation to go to the end but it's ugly. I didn't find a "good" solution for this yet. I've always saved the height on DocumentReady and animated the height accordingly. Hope someone knows a better solution.

Comment: @ComputerArts Interesting! Wouldn't have thought of it. Post it as answer please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [ComputerArts mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292413/jquery-slidedown-up-and-responsive-designs/12292909#comment16490656_12292413), the problem is that jQuery sets the height of the div explicitly after it finishes the animation. It then reuses this explicit height even after you resize the div in your CSS.

Of course, nowadays, you should probably be using CSS animations for this kind of thing.
(See http://addyosmani.com/blog/css3transitions-jquery/)

If you need a jQuery solution, you could force the height to undefined after the animation is complete, so that jQuery picks up the current CSS height. Although, that changes the behaviour slightly:

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/brianpeiris/8zc5g/show

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var WFover = function () {
            $('#menuWFhover').stop().slideDown(600), function () {
                $('#menuWFhover').height(''); 
            });
        };
        var WFout = function () {
            $('#menuWFhover').stop().slideUp(600), function () {
                $('#menuWFhover').height(''); 
            });
        };

        $('#menuNewBox').mouseover(WFover);
        $('#menuWFhover').mouseover(WFover);
        $('#menuNewBox').mouseout(WFout);
        $('#menuWFhover').mouseout(WFout);

    $(window).resize(function () {
        $.removeData($('#menuWFhover')[0], 'fxshow', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 to you for suggesting CSS3 animations. -1 to Microsoft for not shoving IE updates down our throats to support them.

Comment: This webapp I'm working on needs support for IE7+, so go figure. No css3 animations!

Comment: My suggestion for IE 7/8: Ask/force users to install [Google Chrome Frame](http://google.com/chromeframe) if possible. Also, the link I mentioned above describes how to implement CSS 3 animations with a jQuery fallback.

Comment: Furthermore, are you *absolutely sure* you need to support IE 7? You **should always** target your application at *actual* usage not *assumed* usage. Unless you are developing an intranet application, chances are your IE 7 userbase is less than 1%. Global stats are [already less than 1.5%](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201108-201208).

Comment: @brianpeiris actual usage, it's a quite specific public (yes, I swear. And it's the clients requirement anyhow). But IE8 has zero brain for css3 too. In this case I was just wondering why the slideDown didn't work like I expected, I was doing a tryout more than anything. The rest of the animations are done using positions and widths.

Comment: :( Oh well. I hope you're charging your clients an IE7 tax ;)

Comment: Interesting, thats is something ive faced quiet alot recently. I think using jQuery animations (slideUp, fadeIn etc) for cross-browser support may actulay overkill your webapps performance on a smart phone (assuming you're developing a responsive webapp). PS: I normaly use a different js files for advanced browsers just to get something working equaly smoothly on mobiles